# How to disable update plug in warning for java applet

Tags: java, jsp, applet

I have created dynamic web application using java. I have used applet on my jsp Page.below is code for that.

```
<APPLET archive="SEEGApplet.jar" CODE="com.lifecare.EEGApplet.class" WIDTH=0 HEIGHT=0>
    <param name="prmPatientID" value="${patientName}" />
    <param name="prmInputEXE" value="TestPanel.exe" />
    <param name="prmAppDirectory" value="C:" />
</APPLET>
```

Applet is working perfectly on browser. but only one issue is that while loding jsp page it ask for "**update plug-in... or Run this time"** warning.
[image]

I don't want this type of warning so please show me available way for that.

Comment: Why do you want an out-of-date version of Java in your browser?

Comment: @David Wallace i want use java 7 only not 8.

Comment: Not quite what I asked.  If you have Java 8 in your browser, it will still run your Java 7 code.

Comment: @DavidWallace some corporate systems are written to work with old versions of Java (such as Java 6) and using only Java 8 causes them to not work.

Answer (score 4):

There is no way, because that's a related security feature. The browser is right to disable an outdated plugin. If it's outdated, it's because a newer version is available. A newer version has been released because it fixes security vulnerabilities. Hence, if you could force your applet to use a particular version of the plug-in, you could force your users to use a known vulnerable version of the plug-in, and you in turn could use the known vulnerability to gain control of your users' machine, etc. So just tell your users they need to have a working version of the java plugin. They can go to [here](https://www.java.com/en/download/installed8.jsp) to figure out if they have the correct version of Java installed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set this for each client, there is no way to do it at a server level (because that would be a major security nightmate.

As per [Chrome Help - Blocked plug-ins](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/1247383?hl=en-GB)

First run the plugin once, then go to chrome://plugins/ and then tick "Always allowed to run" next to the Java plugin.